# Filtering Data in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

The problem that I am facing is this. I am not managing figuring out the if statement of when an Item is not found so here I have an Action component  where I am iterating the data from json file. I have also a Context which has Filtering function which I am using to have to globally. Lets get to the point, search funcionality works fine excepet when an game is not found. It should display the 'Game not found' but it is not doing it

```
import React from 'react'
import data from "../data.json";
import {  
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
import { SearchContext } from '../SearchContext';


function Action() {
    const {filterProduct}=React.useContext(SearchContext);

    return (
        <>
          <div className='All'>
             <h2> Browsing Action games</h2>   
             <h4>Browse the newest and most played Action titles on Steam</h4>

            {data[0].action.filter(filterProduct).map((product) => {              
              if(data.product !== undefined){
                 return (
                <span>Game not found</span>
              )}            
              return (               
                <div className='f2p' key={product.id}>               
                    <img alt='product'src={product.image}></img>
                    <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                    <h5>{product.price}</h5>                                    
                    <Link  className='link'  to={{
                     pathname: `/payment/${product.id}`,
                     state: {
                     product, 
                      },
                       }}>
           Buy Now
          </Link>    
        </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
}

export default Action

json
[
  {
    "freetoplay":[{
    "id":"0",
    "image": "/F2P/Smite.jpg",
    "price" : "Free To Play",
    "name" :"Smite" 
    },
  {
    "id":"1",
    "image":"/F2P/Brawhalla.jpg",
    "price" : "Free To Play",
    "name" :"Brawhalla" 
   }

],

import React from 'react';
export const SearchContext =React.createContext(null)
export  default function SearchProvider({children}) {

const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = React.useState("");


function filterProduct(product) {
     return product.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
     }
      return( 
       <SearchContext.Provider 
         value ={{filterProduct, 
                  searchValue,
                 setSearchValue}}>
                 {children} 
        </SearchContext.Provider> 
             
          ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<>
  <div className="All">
    <h2> Browsing Action games</h2>
    <h4>Browse the newest and most played Action titles on Steam</h4>

    {data[0].action.filter(filterProduct).map((product) => {
      {
        !product.name ? (
          <span>Game not found</span>
        ) : (
          <div className="f2p" key={product.id}>
            <img alt="product" src={product.image}></img>
            <h2>{product.name}</h2>
            <h5>{product.price}</h5>
            <Link
              className="link"
              to={{
                pathname: `/payment/${product.id}`,
                state: {
                  product,
                },
              }}
            >
              Buy Now
            </Link>
          </div>
        );
      }
    })}
  </div>
</>;
```

You can check after the filter if you have any products with name. If there is no product with name it should return GAME NOT FOUND message. Please try the above block code.

Comment: I have updated the code block. Can you follow that?

Comment: now I cant see any data displayed at the first let alone search something

Comment: Can you move your filter functionality outside and push all the objects in a new array? You can call it something like filteredProduct. And then loop through filteredProduct array and based on the length of filteredProduct array you can show the components. i.e. if filteredProduct.length is > 0 then show all the product details else show "No products found".